# Jquery UI cannot drag select

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Hi I have a disabled select and I would like to be able to drag it. Even a fake select would be great as long as it looks like a select.

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
     <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
           scale=1">
           <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>  

           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
           <script>
                  $( function() {
                         $( ".draggable" ).draggable();   
                  } );
           </script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
              <select disabled>
                  <option value="">Cannot be dragged</option>
                  <option value="1">One</option>
                  <option value="2">Two</option>
                  <option value="3">Three</option>
              </select>
          </div>
          <div>
              <span class="ui-widget-content draggable">Can be dragged </span>
          </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your looking for something like this https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

As your question is not clearly understood

Comment: Copy the code into a html file and open it in chrome. notice that the "Can be dragged" can be dragged and the " <select disabled>" cannot be dragged. How can I drag the select (the entire select and no more)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a javascript solution. Using css I created a div and set the position to absolute and use it to cover the select. Instead of the click being swallowed by the select it is accepted by the div.

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
     <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
            scale=1">
            <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>  

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
            <script>
                  $( function() {
                         $( ".draggable" ).draggable();   
                  } );
            </script>
            <style>
                .draggable 
                {                   
                    display: inline-block;
                }
                .draggable-input-workaround
                {
                    background-color:transparent;
                    width:100%;
                    height:100%;
                    position:absolute;
                }
            </style>

     </head>
     <body>
          <div class="ui-widget-content draggable" style="border-style:solid" >
            <div class='draggable-input-workaround'>

            </div>
              <select disabled>
                  <option value="">Cannot be dragged</option>
                  <option value="1">One</option>
                  <option value="2">Two</option>
                  <option value="3">Three</option>
              </select>
          </div>
          <div>
              <span class="ui-widget-content draggable">Can be dragged </span>
          </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is bubbling of the Click event. The disabled Select element is causing the Click event to never reach the parent element.

To address this, your wrapper needs to have some white space for the User to be able to click the Div so they can drag it.

Working Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  padding: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
    <select disabled>
      <option value="">Cannot be dragged</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="ui-widget-content draggable">Can be dragged </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, if you're using jQuery Theming, you need to wrap `ui-widget-content` inside a `ui-widget` for proper activation.

I would advise using a Handle if possible:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>
```

With:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
  handle: ".ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm aware of the handle but I need to drag the select.